# Reading AppSettings From subsites web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a a subsite placed in my Default website. In the subsite I want to store variables in it's web.config.

However, whenever I try to retrieve the values, they don't exist in the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.

I have put the website as a website application and created it as virtual directory in IIS, no success...

Does anyone have ane idea?

Thanks!

(btw, I'm using .NET 3.5 and IIS Manager 6)

Answer (score 0):

just FYI your *subsites* are called **Virtual Diretories**

in the `web.config` all you need to do is add this into the file:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myVar1" value="myValue1" />
    <add key="myVar2" value="myValue2" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

the `<appSettings>` is a simple `NameValueCollection` that you can itenerate in your code like:

```
NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

for (int i = 0; i < appSettings.Count; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine("#{0} Key: {1} Value: {2}",
    i, appSettings.GetKey(i), appSettings[i]);
}
```

Is this what you are doing?

Comment: Yes, I know how to use web.configs and appsettings... The problem is that for some reason ASP.NET doesn't pick up the web.config from my subsite

Comment: Ahh, then you need to convert that `subsite`into a **Virtual Directory** as it seams that what you have is just a folder inside the Default Website. Right Click in the Default Website add choose `Add Virtual Directory` and choose the folder where you have your site. So it can act as a stand alone

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain better, I have created the subsite as Virtual Directory (I should really get used to the term :-)), but the problem realy was the URL Rewrite. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,

I've fixed my own issue.

I was using URL Rewrite which caused the server to get a bit confused about the actual location of my project.